# What does "will" add to the meaning of the mentioned sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, future-tense

What does "will" add to the meaning of this sentence? Does it actually add the meaning of future tense?

> Much more could and should be said about this, but the foregoing **will**
>   have to suffice for now.

Comment: It's a figure of speech, "will have to suffice for now" = "meanwhile, it's been said enough about this"

Answer (score 1):

Using **will have to** implies that things are as they are out of necessity rather than choice. (Especially, in this case, because of the introductory *could and should*.)

In other words, the sentence could be rephrased as follows:

> Much more could and should be said about this, but since we can't change anything right now, the foregoing is what we have to deal with at present.

Here, a (better) future situation is implied, but *will* is actually referring to forced events in the present—as determined by the use of **for now**.

Comment: isn't ''forced" implied by "have to"?

Comment: @user157323 My rephrasing of the sentence was meant as an alternative to using *will*. It means the same thing. So, yes. If you simply write *the foregoing have to suffice for now* it would be ungrammatical. (But, also, I was pointing out that *will* isn't an explicit reference to the future.)